# MYSQL starts then crashes after a few second

Tags: mysql, xampp

my mysql that comes with xampp was working fine for a year now but it suddenly crashes after a few second..

here is the log

```
2018-09-13 12:30:34 48 InnoDB: Warning: Using innodb_additional_mem_pool_size is DEPRECATED. This option may be removed in future releases, together with the option innodb_use_sys_malloc and with the InnoDB's internal memory allocator.
2018-09-13 12:30:34 72 [Note] InnoDB: innodb_empty_free_list_algorithm has been changed to legacy because of small buffer pool size. In order to use backoff, increase buffer pool at least up to 20MB.

2018-09-13 12:30:34 72 [Note] InnoDB: Using mutexes to ref count buffer pool pages
2018-09-13 12:30:34 72 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2018-09-13 12:30:34 72 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2018-09-13 12:30:34 72 [Note] InnoDB: _mm_lfence() and _mm_sfence() are used for memory barrier
2018-09-13 12:30:34 72 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
2018-09-13 12:30:34 72 [Note] InnoDB: Using generic crc32 instructions
2018-09-13 12:30:34 72 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 16.0M
2018-09-13 12:30:34 72 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2018-09-13 12:30:35 72 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2018-09-13 12:30:35 72 [Note] InnoDB: The log sequence number 1835037 in ibdata file do not match the log sequence number 5523302532 in the ib_logfiles!
2018-09-13 12:30:36 72 [Note] InnoDB: Restoring possible half-written data pages from the doublewrite buffer...
2018-09-13 12:30:36 72 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segment(s) are active.
2018-09-13 12:30:36 72 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2018-09-13 12:30:36 72 [Note] InnoDB:  Percona XtraDB (http://www.percona.com) 5.6.36-82.2 started; log sequence number 5523302532
2018-09-13 12:30:36 2928 [Note] InnoDB: Dumping buffer pool(s) not yet started
2018-09-13 12:30:36 72 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2018-09-13 12:30:36 72 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
2018-09-13 12:30:36 72 [ERROR] Fatal error: mysql.user table is damaged or in unsupported 3.20 format.
```

Comment: In logs it is saying that increase the buffer pool size change the size to 20 mb and restart the DB

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/197593/mysql-user-table-damaged-suddenly

Answer (score 1):

The error says: Fatal error: `mysql.user table is damaged or in unsupported 3.20 format.`

Warrnings and Notes are not the things that break the service. To try and fix this you can try to use [mysqlcheck](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqlcheck.html)

```
mysqlcheck --all-databases
```

Which will probably tell you that the user table is damaged as the error suggests, and then run:

```
mysqlcheck --repair --all-databases
```

Comment: how do i run this on windows 10 xampp?

Comment: you should find your mysql dir locally (usually it s found somewhere in your xampp dir). Inside you should have mysql, mysqlcheck and other executables, run those from command line and don't forget to add user/pass to command if needed.